# how to get mysql OUTFILE on to client machine when querying remote DB server

Tags: mysql, client, file-io

How to get the outfile onto client system when querying remote database server when a statement like "select * from sometable into outfile 'c:/somefile.txt' " is executed. Is there another command for this that makes it happen. Could someone please give the full command or list of steps for this to be possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> The SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE statement
>   is intended primarily to let you very
>   quickly dump a table to a text file on
>   the server machine. If you want to
>   create the resulting file on some
>   other host than the server host, you
>   normally cannot use SELECT ... INTO
>   OUTFILE since there is no way to write
>   a path to the file relative to the
>   server host's file system.
>
> However, if the MySQL client software
>   is installed on the remote machine,
>   you can instead use a client command
>   such as mysql -e "SELECT ..." >
>   file_name to generate the file on the
>   client host.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html